# MailChimp Api, Error parsing image

Tags: php, curl, base64, mailchimp-api-v3.0

**Error:**

> type: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
>   title: Invalid Resource status: 400 detail: Error parsing image:
>   Sorry, files with no extension are not allowed. instance:
>   ef9dc203-c04a-48bd-95b4-66c46de26b77

**Php Code**

```
    $apikey = GP('mailchimp_api_key');

    $auth       =    base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

    $list = array(

        'name'=>'File Name',
        'file_data'=>'iVBORw....'
        //'file_data'=>'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....'
 );

    $json_post = json_encode($list);

    $ch = curl_init();

    $curlopt_url = 'https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/file-manager/files';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
```

My questions, I want to upload photos via MailChimp Api.

What is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the file extension for the value of the `name` parameter in the `$list` array in your code. The extension must be exactly the same as the file you are uploading.

> ```
> curl --request POST \
> --url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/file-manager/files' \
> --user 'anystring:apikey' \
> --header 'content-type: application/json' \
> --data '{"name": "test.txt", "file_data": "VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBleGFtcGxlIGxpbmUgb2YgdGV4dC4="}' \
> --include
> ```
>
> [File Manager Files](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/file-manager/files/)